# Translating nested SQL SELECT to PySpark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, select, pyspark, hive

Spark version: 2.3
Hive: Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.16.2
Engine: PySpark (Spark SQL)

I would like to write SQL query using Spark functional query but I don't know how to it!

**SQL query**

```sql
select distinct id_p
from table1
where tab1.id_p not in (select distinct id_p from table2)
```

**PySpark query**

```py
tab1 = spark.table("table1")
tab2 = spark.table("table2")
tab1 = tab1.select("id_p").distinct()
tab1 = tab1.filter(f.col("id_p).isin(??????) == False )
```

Comment: source tables table1 and table2 present in which database?

Comment: there are present in the same database ! my issue is that I don't know how to filter based  on all values that are exist in one column in an other table

Comment: ``` 
tab2= df.select('id').distinct()

tab = tab1.filter(func.col("id").isin(tab2.collect()))
```

Answer (score 1):

In PySpark you can do it using anti join:

```py
tab3 = tab1.join(tab2, "id_p", "anti").select("id_p").distinct()
```